# Timestamp of when the branch was pushed in git

Tags: git, timestamp

How to check the timestamp of a branch to know when it was pushed to master(not the commit timestamp) in git?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012768/git-inspect-time-at-which-commit-was-pushed